# uploading files to the folder located outside tomcat server

Tags: java, android, tomcat

I am developing an application in android which communicates with tomcat to make use of rest api.
I also need to donwload some files to the android application (client) from server. These files are stored in a folder located outside tomcat directory on the server.To dowload the files I'm configuring my tomcat simply using :

```
<Context docBase="C:\Images" path="/Images" />
```

I don't think I can make use of servlets to upload download files since my front-end is the android application. Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions.